# N-Deklination von Namen in Genitive Singular

Tags: grammatical-case

I am studying B2 grammar. In the book I am using (I don't know if I should name the actual book here) there is a bullet-point which reads:

> *Name* und *Buchstabe* gehören zur n-Delination, bekommen aber in Genitiv
>   Singular zusätlich zur Endung **-en** ein **-s**.

Then there are some questions. The answer to most questions follow that rule, for example:

> Kennst Du die Bedeutung des Familiennamens Müller?

But this one doesn't:

> Der Hof eines Bauern heißt Bauernhof

Why not? And are there many exceptions to the rule given in the textbook? In other words is it a valid rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nouns *Name* und *Buchstabe* appear nowhere in the sentence:

> Der Hof eines Bauern heißt Bauernhof.

Therefore, the rule you quoted doesn't apply.

Comment: I misread the rule.